# How can i Solve Problem "X-Total-Count "?

Tags: reactjs, sails.js, react-admin

My Backend is with Sails.js ,
I install React-admin and this Package ra-data-json-sails
this is my Code
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUmD.jpg]

and i saw this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8G6zs.jpg

Plz Help me

Thanks

Comment: Please make it a habit to include code and error messages as text. That way, other users don't have to follow the links, the question does not rely on other resources and, most importantly, it becomes easier to discover by search engines.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to adding the X-Total-Count header in your CORS configuration, you must also return it in the API response to GET_LIST.

This example implementation should help you:

```
  async.parallel({
    data: getData,
    count: getTotalCount
  }, function (err, results) {
    res.set('X-Total-Count', results.count);
    res.ok(results.data);
  });
```

More details at https://gist.github.com/aantipov/8ee3b7607ab9e01e4ede